# How to toggle a cog on and off per server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Sorry for not writing any code in here.

My question is if I could toggle a cog on and off per server using `self.bot.unload_extension` or with any other command.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can unload a cog with a command, it's not a problem, but it will be unloaded for all the bot. A bot is not a running script for each server, but a single script. But you cand add checks or verification to stop access to commands for a single guild (or a list of guilds) ([see commands.checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check))

Comment: @Baptiste, cogs and extensions are different, cogs are simply classes, extensions are files. But yes - a cog check would do the trick

Comment: My bad... I had read the discord.py documentation but missed it, very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cogs have a special check method, called `cog_check`. You can simply overwrite it and use it as a normal check:

```py
class SomeCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._whitelisted_guilds = [] # List of IDs of the whitelisted guilds


    def cog_check(self, ctx): # Can be a coroutine
        if ctx.guild.id in self._whitelisted_guilds:
            return False
        return True


    @commands.command()
    async def foo(self, ctx):
        # ...
```

If the check fails, `commands.CheckFailure` is raised.

#### Reference:

- [`Cog.cog_check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_check)

Comment: can I use cog_check if it's an event and not a command?

Comment: oh what can i use for events

Comment: A simple if statement inside of it, or make your own decorator